# Laravel Eloquent Relationships (projects and its issues)

Tags: laravel

What I want to do is show the issues in a selected project

HomeController that show the projects that is assigned to a user.

```
public function index()
{
    $companies = auth()->user()->companies;
    $projects  = Project::whereIn('company_id',$companies->pluck('id'))->get();

    return view('home',compact('companies','projects'));
}
```

Home.blade.php that shows projects of the user

```
@forelse($projects as $project)
    <div class="bg-pink-700 h-32 rounded-md p-5 transition duration-500 ease-in-out hover:bg-black transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110s">
        <a href="{{ route('projects.show', $project->id) }}" class="text-xl font-bold m-5 text-white">{{$project->title}}</a>
        <p>{{$project->description}}</p>
    </div>
@empty

@endforelse
```

How do I make the project card/title clickable so it will show the issues within the project?

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question itself and not as links. I'm not going to a 3rd party site in order to be able to know what's happening (and especially not imgur)

Comment: I'm sorry. I am just new here. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code in your Project model

```
public function issues(){
       return $this->hasMany(Issue::class);
}
```

then you can use it like that

```
$project = Project::find(1);
$issues = $project->issues;
```